# How to delete a content in a view with view rules?

Tags: views, rules

I got two views that displayed two different type of contents. Content A got a field "Title" and content B got the same field. I want to find and delete any number of content of type B that got the same title of a content A. I try to do this with view rules module with some view loops. I found some content B that got a title equal to a title of content. How to delete them?

Comment: Do you want a visual interface for this, and do you want to select which duplicates to delete or not?

Comment: Your question is very broad, can you be more specific about the workflow you are looking to implement?

Comment: Look at this link for more details http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131289/compare-two-views-that-present-two-different-content-type-and-delete-nodes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you could potentially use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) (also known as VBO).