# Compare two views that present two different content type and delete nodes

Tags: views, rules

this question is like this: [How to delete a content in a view with view rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131197/how-to-delete-a-content-in-a-view-with-view-rules)

I didn't know why but i make this question with another account that i cannot got access now
So the problem is: I got two views. View A and View B. View A rapresent contents of type A (30 contents for example) and view B rapresent contents of type B (30 contents for example). By comparing the various nodes contained in these two views i want to found (among the nodes contained in the view B) contents with the same title of some nodes caontained in the view A and delete them. After this operation, View A got 30 nodes and View B got 3 nodes because got 27 nodes with same title of some nodes in the View A. I try to do this in a Rule with view loop but i didn't know how to delete nodes with the same title. I try with VBO but i cannot make this process i think, cause i need to delete nodes selectively

Thanks and sorry for the duplicate post (i need to do this cause i cannot reply with old account)

Comment: Use the **Contact** link in the footer, and ask to have the accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that by using the [Remove Duplicates](https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_duplicates) module.

> This module helps the administrator to easily remove duplicate nodes according to one of the node fields.

Comment: I can make a rule using this module?

Comment: @Vittaz I think so. you may need to write custom coding for that. But using this module you delete duplicate nodes at admin/config/content/remove_duplicates